# Отрытие в окне по верх текущего

Tags: html

Много раз видел реализацию на других сайтах. Ты кликаешь по ссылке, а она загружается поверх текущего окна браузера новым окном. Причем не полным экраном, а в свернутом состоянии. Немного похоже на фреймы из delphi.

Как можно создать такое окно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы указать размеры открываемого окна, придется использовать **javascript**:

```
<a href="http://www.google.ru/" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'frame',
'left=50,top=50,width=720,height=480,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" >Открыть Google</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.